# Not able to Redirect to another page in magento in my custom module

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, http-redirect

I have create module for testing and try to call redme action from url. and all config all complete and all is work good but. in my redme action magento not redirect to another page

```
<?php

class Test_Demo_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();     
        $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('capacityweb/Test','Test',array('template' => 'capacity/web/test.phtml'));
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('content')->append($block);
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

public function redmeAction()
    {
    $this->loadLayout();     
    $this->renderLayout();

    $action=$this->getRequest()->getParam('action');        
    $id=$this->getRequest()->getParam('id');


    if($action!=null && $id!=null)
    {
    $relContact = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();   
    }

    Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect("http://google.com");
}

}
```

i have use this code for redirect

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect("http://google.com");
```

but not able to redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
$this->_redirectUrl('http://google.com');
```

Instead of

```
Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect("http://google.com");
```

Comment: yet not redirect to another page. this way need config change in config.xml ?

Comment: this means you have some output somewhere in your code. This is caused in most of the cases by closing the php tag (`?>`) in a class file and having a space or new line after it.